# How to restore data for individual app from iCloud?

Tags: iphone, icloud

I accidentally deleted an app on the iPhone. The data was lost as well. The data was backed up on iCloud only. How can I restore that app with data from iCloud without restore entire system?

Thanks

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the steps below to restore the app with data from iCloud:

1. Make sure your iPhone/iPod/iPad is connected to Wi-Fi and plugged into the charger.
2. Select the option Restore From iCloud Backup.
3. Enter your iCloud account and password.
4. Choose the recent backup you wish to restore to your iOS device.
5. Enter any passwords required when prompted.

Comment: Got new data now after reinstall the app. I don't think it would be able to merge them. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 6):

The answer @LordNeckbeard gave is the “ALL or Nothing” iCloud restore. You get everything in the iCloud backup, or you get nothing from it. Apple doesn’t allow users to selectively restore apps from iCloud.

But you can try some iPhone data restore tool for example iMyFone D-Port Pro. It supports to restore only one apps from backups.